# Best design pattern for fragment activity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Before Ice Cream Sandwich/Honeycomb came on the scene, developers used to craft the flow of logic around an activity, to handle a screen's UI interaction. I am faced with a task of making a combined tab/view-pager with each tab acting as a fragment activity.

The end result is that either its down to my original code appear to be messy or a bad approach to designing fragment activities!

Consider this, one activity that manages one screen and that activity controls all UI aspect for that screen. Now, with using ActionBarSherlock, I've moved the screen UI controls into a fragment activity's layout, now there's a main activity with tab handling mechanism for swiping from one tab to the next, like what it used to be before, starting a intent to launch another activity.

My question is this: what is the best way to split up the original code now that its in a fragment activity? I've thought about using handlers to pass around the messages internally from the fragment activity to the main activity, but it turns out to be what I feel, is the wrong approach.

I am using ActionBarSherlock for this.

Have searched but could not find a concrete example of this scenario and how to approach it.

**Edit:** After comments from CommonsWare, this is the intention, look at the second image shown here on http://androiduipatterns.com "Lewis Llewellyn and Facebook" screenshot, that's what I'm trying to achieve..

Before: `Activity` that handled the UI aspects for one screen.

Now: `SherlockFragmentActivity` with `ViewPager` with a Tab-host, that is the "main" activity of the apk, and each tab fragment extending from `SherlockFragment`. And each tab is now a screen with UI controls in it.

Comment: "a combined tab/view-pager with each tab acting as a fragment activity" -- activities inside of activities (i.e., `ActivityGroup`) is deprecated. Half of the point behind fragments was to get away from activities inside of activities.

Comment: am referring to something like google's play store layout, where you swipe and the view changes... look at the second image shown here on http://www.androiduipatterns.com/ "Lewis Llewellyn and Facebook" screenshot, that's what I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: That is a `FragmentActivity`, holding a `ViewPager`, which uses probably a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, which holds fragments. There are no nested activities, in all likelihood.

Comment: ahhh that's the keywords... I will edit to clarify - thanks for that CommonsWare :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, each fragment in the `ViewPager` deals with itself, because it does not know what other fragments might presently exist. Any events in that fragment that might affect other fragments, or the activity as whole, can be passed passed to the hosting activity via `getActivity()`, possibly casting it to an interface if you plan on hosting this fragment from multiple activities. No `Handler` required.

Comment: Yeah I can visualize it like this in what you're saying, lift off the code that was originally in the activity and drop it into the FragmentActivity instead so to keep it isolated from others?

Comment: @t0mm13b: Well, I can't comment on that part, as that implies a deep understanding of what you presently have, and I can't see your monitor from over here.

Comment: lol! Fair enough so, yeah. That is a fair comment :) +1 from me. I guess there is a moral to this story!

Answer (score 2):

So i suppose what you want is not replicating code across different fragments, amiright? What i do in the case of very similar fragments is create a basefragment with the identical code from which i extend. The other option, something Google does often i noticed, is creating helper classes with the (static) methods.
In any case make sure to never call a fragment from a different fragment.